# Prolog print certain element in list

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list G=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]. and T list which has elements [apple, grape, a, pear, f, orange, durian]. I want to do printing like FirstElement in T -> element in G -> LastElement in T
eg. apple, a, f, durian. My problem now only able to show apple -> durian but no a, f printed.

```
G=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j].

in(a,'1').
in(b,'2').
in(c,'3').
........

printFormat(Prev,[H|T]) :- not(member(H,G)), printFormat(X,T).
printFormat(Prev,[H|T]) :- member(H,G]), in(H,I) write(' -> {'), write(H), write(' -> '), write(I), write('}'), printFormat(X,T).
printFormat(Prev,[Last]) :- write(' -> '), write(Last).
```

Comment: Now that you have removed oh/5, you can see that some variable (like X and G in first clause of printFormat) is not bound to any value. So, what value do you expect X can assume there?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
G=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j].
```

as you don't have global variable in Prolog (at least with this syntax). You can rewrite so:

```
g(E) :- memberchk(E, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]).
```

and then use (your first 2 clauses for printFormat could be rewritten as if then else, avoiding duplicate the linear test):

```
printFormat(Prev,[H|T]) :-
  (  (oh(X,H,_,_,_), not(g(H))  % not should be \+
  -> true
  ;  in(H,I)
  -> write(' -> {'), write(H), write(' -> '), write(I), write('}')
  ;  % this mismatch should never appear? not in(H,I)
     throw(mismatch)
  ),
  printFormat(X,T).
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can print apple only, then return false.